# Java ftpclient changeworkingdirectory makedirectory

Tags: java, android, ftp

I'm new for Java or even android. Now, I have to use the ftpclient from org.apache. However, there's some problem in my directory name like `123_Andy?`. I cannot `changeWorkingDirectory` or even `makeDirectory` due to the question mark. So, my problem is how I can retrieve only part of the directory name, then change the working directory.

Comment: What do you mean by "how I can retrieve only part of the directory name"?. What is your expected output.

Comment: Mmm.. I don't know how to explain it, may I say it about `capture` the word?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to encode the question mark.
Try with `123_Andy%3F`.

[%3F is encoding for ?](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Also check if your library has a provision for URL Encoding. If so use that

Comment: Thanks, I will search that if the URL encoding in my lib.